# Draw a common outline for the intersecting UIViews (ObjectiveC)?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uiview, border

I have a `UIView`. Inside this `UIView`, I have two intersecting subviews. I want to draw a common outline between these two sub-`UIViews`. How do I get about this?

To make it clear:

```
[mainView addSubview:subView1];
[mainView addSubview:subView2];
```

I need to draw an outline for both these intersecting `UIView`s.

Comment: there are no easy build-in options to archieve this. I can think of multiple ways you could draw an common outline. For Example you can add two Views below your subviews with rects extending the originals so you can see an outline. [http://whathaveyoutried.com](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine shapes of both rectangles and create new sublayer from the final shape. This layer will act as your outline.

See my code, its fully commented:

```
//  Create shape of merged rectangles
UIBezierPath *outlinePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:subView1.frame];
[outlinePath appendPath:[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:subView2.frame]];

//  Configure the outline
UIColor *outlineColor = [UIColor redColor];
CGFloat outlineWidth = 1.0f * [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];

//  Create shape layer representing the outline shape
CAShapeLayer *outlineLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
outlineLayer.frame = mainView.bounds;
outlineLayer.fillColor = outlineColor.CGColor;
outlineLayer.strokeColor = outlineColor.CGColor;
outlineLayer.lineWidth = outlineWidth;

//  Set the path to the layer
outlineLayer.path = outlinePath.CGPath;

//  Add sublayer at index 0 - below everything already in the view
//  so it looks like the border
//  "outlineLayer" is in fact the shape of the combined rectangles
//  outset by layer border
//  Moving it at the bottom of layer hierarchy imitates the border
[mainView.layer insertSublayer:outlineLayer atIndex:0];
```

Output looks like this:

[image]

**Edit**: I misunderstood the question at first. Below is my original answer which outlines rects intersection.

You can just create another view which will be representing the intersection and add it above the two subviews. It's frame would be intersection of the `subView1` and `subView2` `frame`s. Just give it clear background color and border using its `layer` property

Your code could look like this:

```
//  Calculate intersection of 2 views
CGRect intersectionRect = CGRectIntersection(subView1.frame, subView2.frame);

//  Create intersection view
UIView *intersectionView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:intersectionRect];
[mainView addSubview:intersectionView];

//  Configure intersection view (no background color, only border)
intersectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
intersectionView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
intersectionView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
```

[image]

Comment: I am sorry but what I really want is the COMMON OUTLINE. Both these views in the image are intersecting but the red line is not a common outline.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question at first. See my edited answer, hope it helps

Comment: You're welcome. If this is what you want, you might consider accepting my answer as a little reward :-)